# Language choice: C++ or C# for Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I'm looking for general opinion about which language would be best. Best in regards to many considerations.

I have a pretty strong background in c, c++, and objective-c. I feel quite comfortable with those 3. I have used very little c#. I've worked in firmware and middleware for over a decade and have moved into mobile apps lately. Mostly iOS, but now expanding to Windows RT.

I am about to write a version of my company's app for Windows Store (or Metro depending on what you want to call it). I did a proof of concept a couple months back using C++/CX. There were are few hurdles learning it (the syntax for ref classes, and the heavy use of namespaces), but that is in the past and I feel quite comfortable with it at this point.

Some drawbacks that I found were that most of the examples (both MSDN and private) of .net are in c# with fewer in c++. It also seemed to be a little tougher to get questions answered concerning .net frameworks with c++. Most of the time people would post a c# answer and I'd need to port it to c++ equiv. Sometimes this is easy, sometimes more difficult.

My question is: Would it be worth my time and my company's time to start over with c# instead of continuing in c++? I'd need to pick up c#, but I don't consider that a huge burden (actually looking forward to it). Some concerns are:
* Acquiring an more engineers down the road to work on this code. Our company will grow shortly. Will it be easier to find an engineer that knows c# vs MS's specialized c++/cx?
* Ease of getting help though examples, articles, and forums. If c# is much more common, that's useful. 
* Compatibility between 3rd party libraries (Seems like WinRT components can be used from any of the main languages)
* Advantages of C# over C++? They both offer everything I need for this app, at least that I can see. What are some pitfalls of C#?
* Does c# use the continution/lambdas for asych programming in the same manner as C++/CX?

Are there any other pros/cons that I'm not thinking of?

What do YOU think? Also, what do YOU have experience with? Why do you back your answer?

Comment: As a C# developer who came from C, C# is a wonderful language. Definitely worth making the switch IMHO.

Comment: This is a textbook "Not Constructive" question.

Comment: I would say while it has a risk of getting very subjective answers - there are lots of datapoints here that could help people make a decision and potentially help a lot of people.

Comment: @FilipSkakun That may or may not be true, but SO has decided that because of the problems that stem from these types of questions in a Q/A environment that they aren't acceptable on this site.  You can go to chat, or a forum, to ask such questions

Comment: I still gave some data points by editing DWright's answer that hopefully won't get me kicked off of SO. :) Perhaps you could ask more, more specific questions that would fit SO format more, like the ones from your bullet points.

Answer (score 1):

C# would have the better online support (code examples, answers to questions), and the stronger base of engineers.  I mean that in this specific situation, for this kind of strongly Microsoft APIs reliant software development.  Windows Store highly important in Microsoft's overall strategy and C# is more important in their language strategy than C++.  Thus, C# is the right fit, IMO.

---

*EDIT (Filip Skakun) I know reopening the question might be hard, so I can't answer it separately but I typed in all this text that could be useful, so I thought I'd add it below:

It is up to you to decide of course and it might be a very subjective choice depending on what you believe in, like if you think the higher potential productivity and better tooling and documentation support of C# outweighs the benefits of a faster, closer to the metal and (slightly subjectively) more portable C++ that you already know. C++ is still almost twice as popular as a language based on the tiobe index, so getting C++ developers might be easier than C# ones. C++/CX is something you only need to use for cross-assembly communication and talking to the WinRT library, but anything else you code should be done in the standard C++ based on all expert recommendations. Also note that C++/CX is not a managed language and you don't use it with .NET. It is highly similar in syntax though to C++/CLI which is a managed language. The good thing about WinRT is that you can use both languages if you want or need to. I use C# for all the XAML UI, networking, business logic etc. There are tons of samples for using C# with XAML while limited range of ones for C++ since it only became available and recommended for XAML platforms with WinRT. On the other hand for anything lower level like working with DirectX or CPU intensive tasks I use C++, since there is more documentation for straight DirectX than the open-source .NET wrappers for it and it performs better when you want to squeeze out all the potential power of the CPU or use the least energy from the battery.

C# is a bit cleaner language than C++ with less punctuation, the new async/await keywords that make async calls (which you must use in Windows 8 apps) a lot cleaner. It is also a managed language so in most cases you might not need to care about when memory gets released, about buffer overruns etc. Debugging C# code yields more deterministic results than C++ (I just spent 2 days debugging some C++ code and I still don't know how far along I am in finding the bug). It is also easier to maintain legacy code since debugging is so much easier.

C++ is faster, so it also uses less battery, your application will start faster and possibly use less energy. If you already know it well then you might have an advantage over the managed development crowd building apps out there. Because it doesn't use garbage collection - memory management is more deterministic and lightweight, so your animations will be more fluid.

Then there is also the motivation factor. If you really want to learn C# - you might be more happy, motivated and productive learning C# than the language you already know and will happily spend more hours learning it than you would be willing to spend writing another C++ app.

The underlying WinRT libraries are the same regardless of which language you use, but the .NET libraries are only available in .NET code and the standard C++ libraries are only available in native code.

Finally - regardless of what decision you make - you can always mix both languages. That could add to maintenance costs since whoever maintains the code in the future might need to know both languages and also the mixed language platform is very young, slightly less supported by the tools (you can't do mixed managed+native remote debugging for example) and potentially more buggy. It is a very good choice in many cases for the reasons I stated earlier though.

Comment: Just want to point out, for the sake of readers' understanding, that only the first paragraph is mine, and it represents a different opinion/approach/scope than the all the remaining paragraphs, which are Filip's.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just hacked (social engineered) Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: I see what you did.  I'm not sure it was an entirely even-handed way to to treat my content, regardless of the merits of what I said.

Comment: Sorry, if you want I can remove mine. Maybe I'll write a blog post instead and link from a comment... :)

Comment: Nah, it can stand as is.

Comment: DWright, Thanks for your initial opinion. Sorry your post got hijacked, but there we no way for Filip to post since this thread was closed. @Filip, thank YOU for your verbose input. This is exactly the kind of dialog I was hoping to generate with this post. 

I have decided to go ahead and start over with C# for several reasons, including several of your points. Plus I'm ready to learn something new. 

I can't imagine I'd need the advantages that C++ offers in this app. It's a photo based application (not editing or anything like that, rather just showing data from a webservice).